# Calculate margin using AccessibilityNodeInfo

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am developing an accessibility service on android and I want to check the space between on-screen elements. Currently I am already using AccessibilityNodeInfo and its getBoundsInScreen() method to read the touch target size of clicked elements.

Do you know if there is a way to retrieve the margin of an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not.  Anything that you came up with would be a hack.

You could compare the on screen coordinates of elements.  But, then you're not going to get a "margin" just the space between them.  There is no way to get a "margin" property.